# How to get php date from MySQL database to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

i'm a new web developer.i have following script ,where in `endDate` instead of `06:39:00 pm` , I want to get time from mysql database, where I already insert time like `06:39:00`. How can I get time from Mysql Database to this script? any body please help me?

the script is ,

```
<script>
 var config = {
            endDate: 'May 28 2016 06:39:00 pm',
            timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka',
            hours: $('#hours'),
            minutes: $('#minutes'),
            seconds: $('#seconds'),
            newSubMessage: 'Iftar Remaining Time is Up'
        };
</script>
```

my php code is like ,

```
<?php
                        $date= date("Y-m-d");
                        $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `data` where `date`='$date' ");
                        $row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);

                        ?>
    .....
    .....
    <?php $time=$row2['iftar']; ?>
```

i want to input  $time  instead of 06:39:00 pm in endDate

Answer (score 0):

You will need to collect the data from php then pass the variable to JavaScript like follows:

```
<?php
    $date = // Method of collecting date from table
?>
```

Then at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = "<?= $date?>";
</script>
```

you can then access this date variable in JavaScript using `date`